# Viewport Glitches when using large scale objects

Tags: 3d-view

I am currently working on a simulation to see how the earth would be affected and or how humans would be affected if the sun turned off for 1 second. whenever I add in a line to show the distance between the sun and the earth, and I go to the end of said line, the entire view port begins to glitch. [image]

The Clip start is 1m and the end is 1000m. this is currently the best clip size result that I could find, increasing/decreasing the clip size only makes this effect worse